# How to make bootstrap 4 dropdown exactly below the parent component in every dynamic width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

let say I have a navbar and I lock my navbar with `max-width: 1600px` and `margin: 0px auto` so my navbar component stay in the middle of it container no matter how much width the device take. But I got one problem when using a dropdown, it seems my dropdown always go to the most right part of the screen. I already try to delete `dropdown-menu-right` but it just make the dropdown go to the left, can someone help me to solve this?

this is what I got right now:

[image: You can see in here, dropdown menu has an offside position].

This is what I expect to get:

[image: This is what I want, where the dropdown exactly below the parent no matter what the device screen width is]

in some case, I tried to change it position to relative, but it make my layout git worse, when I'm using absolute, at first it can fix the problem, but when I try it in a different device, the position is breaking again

this is the example of my code:

```
              <div
                :class="
                  isLalaVoucherMenuActive
                    ? 'dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right show'
                    : 'dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right'
                "
              >
                <button class="dropdown-item">
                  <router-link
                    to="/auth/login"
                    :class="
                      isLalaVoucherHomeActive
                        ? 'nav-link active-nav-link'
                        : 'nav-link'
                    "
                    @click.native="toLalaVoucherHome()"
                    >Lala Land</router-link
                  >
                </button>
                <button class="dropdown-item">
                  <span
                    :class="
                      isLalaVoucherHomeActive
                        ? 'nav-link active-nav-link'
                        : 'nav-link'
                    "
                    @click="openPaymentMethod()"
                    style="cursor: pointer"
                    >lala Voucher</span
                  >
                </button>
              </div>
```

this is my css:

```
.navbar .dropdown-menu {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  right: -120px;
}
```

Can someone help me to solve this? I'm quite confused about it

EDIT 1:

[image: When using relative, it works but, it break my layout (it makes my list into 2 lines)]

this is my css when using `position: relative`:

```
.navbar .dropdown-menu {
   width: 200px;
   position: relative;
   top: 100px;
   left: -120px;
}
```

Comment: Does changing `position: relative;` to `position: absolute;` in `.navbar .dropdown-menu` solve your problem?  also your provided html code doesn't have a `.navbar` class.  maybe change that to only `.dropdown-menu` and see if it works too.

Comment: @John Thankyou for your response, when I try to use relative, it does solve the off side position of the dropdown, but it break my navbar layout, you can see the images in my EDIT 1 section

Comment: Can you add more HTML code? I don't think its all there.  Also I recommended to change to `position: absolute;`

Comment: @John okay, I'll replicate it first